# Problems with urls.pyc files generated in django, how to fix it?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

We have made ​​an application in django 1.6.4 upgraded to Django 1.7, I use nginx and gunicorn to serve the application.

Randomly the app returns the following error:

```
TypeError at /admin/ihs_booking/occupancydiscount/add/
 'tuple' object is not callable
 Request Method:    POST
 Request URL:   http://localhost/admin/ihs_booking/occupancydiscount/add/
 Django Version:    1.7
 Exception Type:    TypeError
 Exception Value: 'tuple' object is not callable
 Exception Location:    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py in message_user, line 1016
 Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
 Python Version:    2.7.6
```

We tried changing apache to try but still the same problem.

After investigating we concluded that the problem occurs with urls.pyc generated.

We delete the pyc, restart the server (apache or nginx + gunicorn) and it works.

After a while the problem starts again.

This is the content of urls.py:

```
#-*- coding=utf-8 -*-
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from .views import home, search, book, confirm_payment, gestion, contact_ihs, test_calendar

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
 # Examples:
 # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
 url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
 url(r'^calendar/$', test_calendar, name='test_calendar'),
 url(r'^search/$', search, name='search'),
 url(r'^gestion/$', gestion, name='gestion'),
 url(r'^book/$', book, name='search'),
 url(r'^confirm-payment/$', confirm_payment, name='confirm'),
 url(r'^contact/', contact_ihs, name='contact'),
 url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls),)
)

 #Defining the URLs to upload media files
if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += patterns(
     'django.views.static',
     (r'media/(?P<path>.*)',
     'serve',
     {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

We must run the app with nginx + gunicorn because need to run django and php in the same server.

Any idea? 
Thanks!

Here the admin/options.py that around the 1061 line.

```
def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url='', obj=None):
    opts = self.model._meta
    app_label = opts.app_label
    preserved_filters = self.get_preserved_filters(request)
    form_url = add_preserved_filters({'preserved_filters': preserved_filters, 'opts': opts}, form_url)
    view_on_site_url = self.get_view_on_site_url(obj)
    context.update({
        'add': add,
        'change': change,
        'has_add_permission': self.has_add_permission(request),
        'has_change_permission': self.has_change_permission(request, obj),
        'has_delete_permission': self.has_delete_permission(request, obj),
        'has_file_field': True,  # FIXME - this should check if form or formsets have a FileField,
        'has_absolute_url': view_on_site_url is not None,
        'absolute_url': view_on_site_url,
        'form_url': form_url,
        'opts': opts,
        'content_type_id': get_content_type_for_model(self.model).pk,
        'save_as': self.save_as,
        'save_on_top': self.save_on_top,
        'to_field_var': TO_FIELD_VAR,
        'is_popup_var': IS_POPUP_VAR,
        'app_label': app_label,
    })
```

We've got a "," at the end of the list_display in the admin.py, we removed it but the error still occurs.

This is a class of the admin.py:

```
  class PromcodeDiscountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('code', 'hotel', 'name', 'discount_percentage', 'start', 'end', 'is_active', 'promotional_group')
    form = PromocodeAdminForm
  admin.site.register(PromcodeDiscount, PromcodeDiscountAdmin)
```

Comment: What urls does this happen for? Is it just this one?

Comment: What makes you think that the problem is related to .pyc or urls.py? Can you paste the code of `/admin/options.py, around line 1016`

Comment: You have a tuple missing a comma. Somewhere in your code you have something like `(('a','b') ('c','d'))` or possibly `('a','b')()`; however without looking at your `admin.py` for you application its difficult to determine much.

Comment: I pasted the code of /admin/options.py, around line 1016.

Comment: @koopa: this does not tell us which line is #1016

Comment: Testing we note that the problem is exclusively with the urls.pyc, deleting and restarting the problem is resolve.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers the 1061 line is "context.update({"

Comment: @koopa : Your problem is __not__ solved. The url.pyc file is automatically created (if missing) or updated (if older than urls.py) byt the Python interpreter when the module is loaded. You'll keep on getting this error again and again and again after each restart.

Comment: After delete de pyc and restart the server, the new pyc is generated but randomly the problems occurs again

Comment: It's not "randomly" generated, it's generated by the first python interpreter importing this module. All of this is documented, that's just how Python works. And it has nothing to do with the module being loaded from a .py or .pyc file, it's either a coding error or something that broke when updating from 1.6.x - but most probably a coding error.

Comment: If you only get the error for admin/ihs_booking/xxx urls, then the problem is in your ihs_booking/admin.py module, and most probably on one of the `self.has_XXX_permissions` call.

Comment: I mean that the problem is randomly generated, not the pyc; we know that the pyc is generated from the python interpreter.

Comment: @schillingt is not a particular url case, happens in any

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i've update the issue with an extract of the admin.py

Answer (score 0):

i know it's a yearago question but for future reference,
delete the last comma from
 `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls),)`